# Dojo: override Input's validator in the Form

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

There is a form with 2 fields and a Submit button. For example:

```
<form data-dojo-id="fooForm" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">
  <input data-dojo-id="input1" data-dojo/type="ValidationTextBox />
  <input data-dojo-id="input2" data-dojo/type="ValidationTextBox />
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I would like to override `input2` validator function like this:

```
...
input2.validator = function() {
  console.debug('custom validator');

  return true;
}
...
```

The problem is that once I hit Submit button, and form's validation occurs - it ignores custom validator.

How to properly override some inputs validator in the form?

Comment: you are returning `true` value so your custom validator will always pass the form validation. You need to return either `true` or `false` based on your business logic.

Comment: can you please share the jsfiddle with problem statement?